# pexpect can't pass input over 1024 chars?

Tags: python, macos, io, expect, pexpect

I'm currently passing some input to a process with pexpect with the following code:

```
p = pexpect.spawn('cat', timeout=5.0 )
p.maxread = 5000
p.setecho(False) # prevent the process from echoing stdin back to us
INPUT_LEN = 1024
p.sendline('a'*INPUT_LEN)
print p.readline() # pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

When INPUT_LEN < 1024, everything works fine, but **for >= 1024 characters, the process does not receive the full input**, causing raising a "pexpect.TIMEOUT" error on p.readline().

I've tried splitting my input into pieces smaller than 1024 characters, but this has the same issue:

```
p = pexpect.spawn('cat', timeout=5.0 )
p.maxread = 5000
p.setecho(False)
INPUT_LEN = 1024
p.send('a'*1000)
p.sendline('a'*(INPUT_LEN-1000))
print p.readline() # pexpect.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded in read_nonblocking().
```

Does anyone know how to make pexpect work with inputs over 1024 characters? I tried looking at the source, but it just seems to be calling os.write(...).

(As a side note, I've noticed the same truncation error occurs when I run "cat" from a shell and attempt to paste in >=1024 characters with "Cmd+V". However, everything works fine if I run "pbpaste | cat" .)

Thanks!

**Update:**
The call to "os.write()" returns 1025, indicating a successful write, but os.read() returns "\x07" (the single character BEL), and then hangs on the next call, resulting in the timeout.

Dividing the os.write() call into two sub-1024 byte write()s, separated by a call to os.fsync(), does not change anything.

Comment: `pexpect.spawn` should have a `maxdata` keyword by default set to `2000`, so probably this wont apply to your case, but have you tried increasing it?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work; see latest edit

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wrote maxdata but I meant `maxread`, well it was worth a try I guess.

Comment: Digging a little more into the source code I see that it use `pty` and `fcntl`, this may the root of your 1024 buffer limit. Could you provide python version and platform?

Comment: python version is "Python 2.7", and platform is OSX 10.6.8 ("Darwin tba.local 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem seems to be MacOS related, take a look at [**MacOSX 10.6.7 cuts off stdin at 1024 chars**](https://superuser.com/q/264407).

It basically says that 1024 is your tty buffer limit.

I'm not an expert on Mac OS, but maybe others can give you more informations about this.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to work around this at the python level? e.g. by writing 1023 bytes, flushing the buffers, then writing the rest?

Comment: @tba: From what you're explaining the problem seems to be on the read side. So I think you're stack with a pipe approach (as the one that pbpaste have), but I fear that will probably nullify your effort of using pexpect.

Comment: Unfortunately, using pipes with python's "subprocess" causes deadlocks: see the "Warning:" about using ".stdin.write" on http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html . The suggested workaround is to use communicate(), which waits for the process to terminate. This won't work for me because I need to send and receive info with the process multiple times before it terminates.

Comment: @tba: If you need to send/recevie back and forth don't use `communicate()`, but don't let that Warning scare you too much: you can use `stdin.write`/`stdout.read`, you "just" need to be careful. On *Unix* you have [`select`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/select.html) (take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2408670/1132524)), while for a cross platform solution (aka *Windows too*) you'll have to use `Threads` (take a look at [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/1132524)).

Comment: Thanks Rik. I previously tried stdin.write and stdin.read but encountered deadlocks, hence the switch to pexpect. Any idea how to debug the deadlocks?

Answer (score 1):

I realise it is very very late, but I am posting a solution for someone who stumbles on to this question with the very same problem (as I did earlier today).

Based on some of the answers/comments, I have written a pexpect like package that uses stdin.write and stdout.read instead of whatever it is that pexpect uses. I have not had a chance to test it would very thoroughly but to this point, it has stood up to the challenge.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/tayyabt/tprocess

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Debian Linux) the limit (4096 chars) was related to the canonical processing input mode of the terminal. There are some comments about that in the [pexpect documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.send).

I solved my problem by turning off canon mode before sending my data:

```
p.sendline('stty -icanon')
p.sendline('a'*5000)
```