# Python subprocess communicate kills my process

Tags: python, subprocess

Why does communicate kill my process?  I want an interactive process but communicate does something so that I cannot take raw_input any more in my process.

```
from sys import stdin 
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Still Running\n")
    x = raw_input()    
    i = 0
    while ('n' not in x ) :
        print("Still Running " + str(i) + " \r\n")
        x = raw_input()
        i += 1

    print("quit")



print(aSubProc.theProcess.communicate('y'))
print(aSubProc.theProcess.communicate('y'))
```

exception!

```
self.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`communicate` and `wait` methods of `Popen` objects, close the `PIPE` after the process returns. If you want stay in communication with the process try something like this:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("some_process", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("input")
proc.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: Your code leads to a deadlock due to buffering. See [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe) Also, `proc.communicate()` closes pipes when it sees EOF that may happen before/after the child process exits. `proc.wait()` doesn't close any pipes. It waits for the child process to exit.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does communicate kill my process?

From the docs for [`Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. ***Wait for process to terminate.***
>   <sup>emphasize mine</sup>

You may call `.communicate()` only once. It means that you should provide all input at once:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen([sys.executable, 'child.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
print p.communicate(os.linesep.join('yyn'))[0]
```

#### Output

```
Still Running

Still Running 0 

Still Running 1 

quit
```

Notice the doubled newlines: one from `'\r\n'` and another from `print` statement itself in your script for the child process.

Output shows that the child process received three input lines successfully (`'y'`, `'y'`, and `'n'`).

Here's a similar code using [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)'s `input` parameter from Python3.4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(['python2', 'child.py'], universal_newlines=True,
                      input='\n'.join('yyn'))
print(output, end='')
```

It produces the same output.

---

If you want to provide a different input depending on responses from the child processes then use `pexpect` module or its analogs to avoid issues mentioned in [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)