# Python subprocess.communicate hangs when parent leaves zombies

Tags: python, multithreading, popen, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to use `Popen` to create a subprocess `A` along with a thread that communicates with it using `Popen.communicate`. The main process will wait on the thread using `Thread.join` with a specified timeout, and kills `A` after that timeout expires, which should cause the thread to die as well.

However, this doesn't seem to work when `A` itself spawns more subprocesses `B`,`C` and `D` with different process groups than `A` that refuse to die. Even after `A` is dead and labelled defunct, and even after the main process reaps `A` using `os.waitpid()` so that it no longer exists, the the thread refuses to join with the main thread.

Only after all the children, `B`, `C`, `D` are killed, does `Popen.communicate` finally return.

Is this behavior actually expected from the module? A recursive wait might be useful in some cases, but it's certainly not appropriate as the default behavior for `Popen.communicate`. And if this is the intended behavior, is there any way to override it?

Here's a very simple example:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading import Thread
import os
import time
import signal

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

proc = Popen(["/bin/bash"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
             stderr=DEVNULL, start_new_session=True)


def thread_function():
    print("Entering thread")
    return proc.communicate(input=b"nohup sleep 100 &\nexit\n")


thread = Thread(target=thread_function)
thread.start()
time.sleep(1)
proc.kill()
while True:
    thread.join(timeout=5)
    if not thread.is_alive():
        break
    print("Thread still alive")
```

This is on Linux.

Comment: where is your code example?

Comment: provided just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this comes from a fairly natural way to write the popen.communicate method in Linux. Proc.communicate() appears to read the stdin file descriptor, which will return an EOF when the process dies. Then it does the wait to get the exit code of the process.

In your example, the sleep process inherits the stdin file descriptor from the bash process. So when the bash process dies, popen.communicate doesn't get an EOF on the stdin pipe, as the sleep still has it open. The simplest way to fix this is to change the communicate line to:

```
return proc.communicate(input=b"nohup sleep 100 >/dev/null&\nexit\n")
```

This causes your thread to end as soon the bash dies... due to the exit, not your proc.kill, in this case. However, the sleep is still running after bash dies if you use the exit statement or the proc.kill call. If you want to kill the sleep as well, I would use

```
os.killpg(proc.pid,15)
```

instead of the proc.kill(). The more general problem of killing B, C and D if they change the group is a more complex problem.

Addtional data:
I couldn't find any official documentation for this method of proc.communicate, but I forgot the most obvious place :-) I found it with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408650/why-does-python-subprocess-hang-after-proc-communicate). The [docs for communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate) say:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.

You are getting stuck at step 2: Read until end-of-file, because the sleep is keeping the pipe open.