# Python code hangs when using a subprocess with a large amout of output to stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I have a subprocess that can output a lot of data to stdout. When too much data is generated it causes the subprocess to hang since it is waiting for the stdout buffer to be emptied.

Here is a small example below...

test.py

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

# test.py

import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python","./_ping_con.py"], stdout = subp.PIPE)

while proc.poll() is None:
    pass

print proc.stdout.read()
```

...and the subprocess:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

# _ping_con.py

print(96000 * "*")   # Hangs here because it's too much data for the stdout pipe
```

What I'd like to know is, can this buffer be expanded to allow for more data to be handled? If not, is there a different way I could be sending my data that would avoid this issue? OR in the main process, is there a way to tell if the stdout buffer is full and do a read?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408650/why-does-python-subprocess-hang-after-proc-communicate

Comment: It's a known bug: "

Note

This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use Popen.communicate() when using pipes to avoid that. "

Comment: @rdas, _known_, yes. I'm not sure that's a _bug_ -- it's behaving as designed and documented.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was writing all my output to a temporary file, then passing the name of the file back to the parent. Works very well!

Comment: While this may work you fixed nothing really. Just masked the problem. You should fix it as per @rdas comment

Comment: How does using Popen.communicate() help if it closes the PIPE before I have finished using it? That's what I found when I looked online for simple examples of using it. My application has no requirement where I need to pass my data via the PIPE.