# Why Popen('ping URL').communicate() works in Windows and doesn't work in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I try to run the code on Ubuntu, which works in Windows:

```
import subprocess 

ARGS = ["ping", "google.com"]
process = subprocess.Popen(ARGS, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

data = process.communicate()
print(data)
```

When run under Windows, this code prints out tuples of ping packages. But the same code running on Ubuntu just hangs and nothing else!

Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does python.subprocess hang after proc.communicate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408650/why-does-python-subprocess-hang-after-proc-communicate)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my case.
1) the question author's code works exclusively in Windows
2) as far as I understood, the problem with the author of the question was that communicate() was trying to run twice for one process. Which is unacceptable, because after the first communicate(), PIPE is closed.
In my case, the situation is completely different: the code in the subprocess works, but the data is not printed via communicate(). Moreover, this only applies to Ubuntu, this code works on Windows without any problems!

Comment: Ping in Windows sends 4 packets and stops. Ping in Ubuntu sends infinite packets until you quit the program. `process.communicate()` waits for EOF, which it gets to in windows, but won't get to in Ubuntu. Try doing `ARGS = ["ping", "-c", "4", "google.com"]` and you should see data printed in Ubuntu.`-c 4` tells ping to send 4 packets only

Comment: As far as I know, ping under Windows also runs indefinitely. To limit the work to four packages for Windows, you need the command ARGS = ["ping", "-n", "4", "google.com"]

Comment: When I ran it on Windows, it only sent 4 packets and stopped without any explicit `-n 4` flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing on Windows, I saw that `ping` in Windows sent 4 packets and stopped. `ping` in Ubuntu, on the other hand, sent infinite packets until quitting the program.

The `process.communicate()` command will wait for end-of-file (EOF) signal, which it gets to in Windows,obviously, but won't get to in Ubuntu. The solution is making `ping` in Ubuntu terminate. You can limit the number of packets `ping` sends with the `-c` flag. Doing  `ARGS = ["ping", "-c", "4", "google.com"]` should get your program to print the results of 4 packets being sent.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `ping` on most platforms is to just send more packets forever. This will look like it "hangs" because your Python code is waiting for the subprocess to finish, but it never will (though eventually you will fill up memory with the buffered output).

You want to add an option to limit the number of packets, something like

```py
result = subprocess.run(
    ['ping', '-c', '4', 'google.com'],
    capture_output=True, check=True, text=True)
data = result.stdout
```

Notice also the use of `subprocess.run()` in preference over the lower-level `Popen` function. Like [the documentation already tells you,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) you don't want to manage the `Popen` object yourself if you can avoid it.